# JavaScript's negative look-ahead doesn't work as expected?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some data in a `textarea` :

(yes it is multiline)

```
"@ObjectTypeID", DbType.In
"@ObjectID", DbType.Int32,
"@ClaimReasonID", DbType.I
"@ClaimReasonDetails", DbTy
"@AccidendDate", DbType.Da
"@AccidendPlaceID", DbType
"@AccidendPlaceDetails", Db
"@TypeOfMedicalTreatment", 
"@MedicalTreatmentDate", Db
"@CreatedBy", DbType.Int32
"@Member_ID", DbType.Strin
.ExecuteScalar(command).ToS
```

In each row - I want to remove those sections : (from `"` (include) till the end of row) :

Visually : ( I sampled only 4  )

[image]

I've managed to do this :

```
   value=value.replace(/\"[a-z,. ]+(?!.*\")/gi,'')
```

Which means : search the first `"` where have charters after it , which doesnot have a future `"`

This will yield the required results :

```
"@ObjectTypeID
"@ObjectID32,
"@ClaimReasonID
"@ClaimReasonDetails
"@AccidendDate
"@AccidendPlaceID
"@AccidendPlaceDetails
"@TypeOfMedicalTreatment
"@MedicalTreatmentDate
"@CreatedBy32
"@Member_ID
.ExecuteScalar(command).ToS
```

**Question:**

I understand why it is working  , but I dont understand why the following is not working :

`value=value.replace(/\".+(?!.*\")/gi,'')`

http://jsbin.com/fanep/4/edit

I mean : it suppose to search `"` where has charters after it , which **doesn't** has future `"` ....

What am I missing ?  I really hate to declare `[a-z,. ]`

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I showed it already  http://i.stack.imgur.com/mU183.jpg :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one that doesn't work fails because the `.+` is *greedy*. It eats up all it can. (Visual tools can help here, such as this one: http://regex101.com/r/eJ5kJ2/1) We can make it clearer that `.+` is matching too much by putting it in a capture group: http://regex101.com/r/qF7nR9/1 Which show us:

[image]

In your one that *does* work (http://regex101.com/r/kR8vL6/1), you've changed that to `[a-z,. ]+`, which means "one or more a to z, comma, period, or space" (note that the `.` there is just a period, **not** a wildcard). That's much more limited (in particular, it doesn't include `@`).

---

Side note: There's no need to escape the `"` with a backslash, `"` isn't a special character in regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

`+` is greedy. Since "the whole thing" matches your rule of "must not have a `"` after", it will go with that.

The reason your first regex works is because you are disallowing most characters by explicitly whitelisting certain ones.

To fix, try adding `?` after the `+` - this will make it lazy instead, matching as little as possible while still meeting the rules.

---

Additionally, you are searching for the stuff you want to keep... and then deleting it.

Try this instead:

```
val = val.replace(/"[^"]*(?=[\r\n]|$)/g,'');
```

This will remove everything from the last `"` to the end of a line (or end of the input).

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> value=value.replace(/\"[a-z,. ]+(?!.*\")/gi,'')
> ```
>
> means: search the first `"` where have charters after it, which doesnot have a future `"`

To be exact: It matches the first `"` that has some of the characters `[a-z,. ]` after it, which then is not (in any distance) followed by another `"`.

> I dont understand why the following is not working:
>
> ```
> value=value.replace(/\".+(?!.*\")/gi,'')
> ```

You have removed the restriction of the character class. `.+` will now match any char, including quotes. Regardless whether greedy or not, it will now find the first `"` that is followed by an amount of any characters (*including other quotes*) that are no more followed by quotes - i.e. it will suffice if `.+` matches until the last quote.

> I really hate to declare `[a-z,. ]`

You can just use the class of all characters except quotes: `[^"]`. Indeed, I think the following lookahead-free version matches your intent better:

```
value = value.replace(/"[^"\n\r]*/gi, '');
```

Comment: *"Indeed, I think the following lookahead-free version matches your intent better"* +1

Answer (score 1):

Why the below regex is not working?

```
\".+(?!.*\")
```

Answer:

`\"` matches the first `"` and the following `.+` would match greedily upto the last character. Because the last character in a line isn't followed by  any character zero or more times plus `\`, the above regex would match the whole line undoubtably.

For your case, you could simply use the below regex to match from the second `"` upto the end of the line anchor.

```
\"[^"\n]*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jL2lG2/4)